# Sed - Cannot capture and replace with curly brackets in a file

Tags: sed, capture, regexp-replace, brackets

I would like to capture and replace with sed the following pattern :

```
{{/tagName}}} to {{/tagName}} }
```

But I cannot figure it out

I have tried

```
sed 's/({{\/.*}})/\1 }/g'
```

But it does not work. It does not capture and the blank space does not work in the 2nd part.
Any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE** :
To be more concise, the question is If I have to replace this pattern in a file with the option -i, how should I do ?

```
 sed -i 's/({{\/.*}})/\1 }/g' ./temp.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or if you'd like [BRE syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-syntax.html), you could do it too. It would be rare case when they are more compact.

```bash
$ sed  's/{{[^{}]\+}}/& /' <<< '{{/tagName}}}'
{{/tagName}} }
```

`&` in replacement the string represents full match of a the regexp part.

**EDIT:** to replace all occurrences if file you can use

```bash
sed -i 's/{{[^{}]\+}}/& /g' ./temp.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$ sed -E 's/\{\{[^\}]+\}\}/& /' <<< '{{/tagName}}}'
{{/tagName}} }
```

`LESS=+/'^ +-E' man sed`

> -E, -r, --regexp-extended

`&` is the matched part

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have updated the question. I was not enough clear in my demand. Thank you

Comment: In some cases `-E` reduces the cognitive overload, in this case I would posit it does not.